# Android. How to download image from Firebase and set it like background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I recently got acquainted with Firebase.

**Task: download an image from the Firebase repository and set it as the background image.**

I managed to download the image. I do this with this code:

```
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://my bucket name");

        StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child("image/20170703_142533.jpg");

        File localFile = null;
        try {
            localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pathReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) 
            {
                Log.d("TAG_LOG", "Downloaded"); 
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) 
            {
                Log.d("TAG_LOG", "Error"); 
            }
        });
```

Proceeding from the fact that the logs are written `Downloaded`, I understand that everything works.

But **where this file was downloaded and how to install it as a background image I do not understand.**

Sorry for my mistakes in text if you found it, English not my national language. I hope i wrote understandable. I count on your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) Creates an empty file in the default temporary-file directory, using
>   the given prefix and suffix to generate its name.

If you want to store the file in your app directory -

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "dir_name");
// Create dir if not exists
if(!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();

File mFile = new File(dir, "file_name");
```

Now, use this `mFile` as a location where the file is to be downloaded...

`pathReference.getFile(mFile).addOnSuccessListener{ ... }`

As you have the location of file, you can do what you want... *set as background*.

Comment: Okay, but how set as background?
I use it when i my image in drawable:
`getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background);`

But what i have to write when i have file?

Comment: To get a bitmap from file - `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath());` convert it to `BitmapDrawable` and set it to background using `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable`